# virtual function with std::move to call reference function

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;


class Parent
{
  virtual void set() = 0;
  virtual void restore() = 0;
};
class Child: public Parent
{
   public:
  void set(){
      cout << "\n Child::set";
  }
  void restore() {
      cout << "\n Child::restore";
  }
  void generate() {
      cout << "\n generate called";
      set();
  }
};
class GrandChild: public Child
{
    public:
  void set(){
      cout << "\n GrandChild::set";
  }
  void restore() {
      cout << "\n GrandChild::restore";
  }   
};

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<Child> aChild = std::make_unique<Child>();
    std::unique_ptr<GrandChild> aGrandChild
        (std::unique_ptr<GrandChild>{static_cast<GrandChild*>
            (std::move(aChild).release())});

    aGrandChild->generate();
    return 0;
}
```

I don't really understand how this function works. If I execute the above function it will print "Child::set".
Would it be possible for this function to print out "GrandChild::set" using `std::move`?

Comment: Do you agree that `aGrandChild` is pointing to an object of type `Child`?

Comment: Why jump through those hoops ? Why do just create the `GrandChild` directly ? What er you trying to do ?

Comment: What exactly is the `std::move` supposed to be doing here? I mean, there's a lot I don't understand with trying to downcast `aChild` into something it's not, but in particular I'm not sure what you think the move _should_ be doing.

Comment: A little remark: In ``Parent`` the virtual member functions are private! I assume you want them to be public?

Comment: Check the [Sanitizer:](https://godbolt.org/z/GqYvYdGq8)

Comment: It sghould be noted that, while this program may compile and run, Your `static_cast` to `<GrandChild*>` invokes Undefined Behavior.  What you are casting is not convertible to `GrandChild*`.  It also does not change the object pointed to into a `GrandChild`.

Comment: What are you trying to do and why?

Answer (score 1):

This code invokes undefined behavior, in that the object created is of type `Child`.  Using static_cast to cast the pointer to a `GrandChild*` is undefined behavior.  `static_cast` relies on the programmer to understand the types, and will perform only the most basic of checks.

`dynamic_cast` would not perform this cast, and would return a `nullptr`, indicating that the cast could not be performed.

As for your question about `std::move()`:  In this case, it does nothing useful and it could be eliminated without changing the behavior of the code.  However, note, the above cast is still a problem.